# Issue with refinerycms I18n Translation Default Frontend Locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locale, refinerycms

Im working with RefineryCMS to upload a blog. Every works fine, but when i change the "I18n Translation Default Frontend Locale (Refinery) - en" to "es" (spanish) only somethings changes in the blog engine, but others desapear.

I want to know where and how i can make the changes to translate the rest of the options and this dont desapear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-blog/blob/master/config/locales/es.yml is the locale file which should be updated to match english version ( https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-blog/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml ). You can add missing translations in your config/locales/es.yml file preserving the structure from files above.

If you could send us a pull request with your changes it would awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, now is fixed and i pull the file to the refinerycms-blog github.